# Why have leading ffffff for single byte

Tags: java, hex, type-conversion

I am reading data some are 1 byte, some are are 2 byte, some are 3 byte etc. For single byte

```
byte qtySat = r.readByte();
```

for 2 bytes I read as

```
int serialNumber = r.readUnsignedShort();
```

The reading is all fine and working well. The problem when I convert to show in hex format I get funny scenarios. For example for

```
Integer.toHexString(qtySat )
```

I get the output as ffffffce but I just want ce ?

Then for Integer.toHexString(serialNumber)
I get output as say A1 but I want the leading 00 A1 cause this 2 byte of data. What changes to Integer.toHexString should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.toHexString(qtySat )` gives you a binary representation of the `int` value passed to it. If you are passing a negative `byte`, it will become a negative `int` of the same value, which explains all the `1` bits you are seeing.

You can use `Integer.toHexString(qtySat & 0xff)` to set all the bits other than the low 8 bits to 0 before converting to hex String.

```
byte qtySat = (byte)0xce;
System.out.println (qtySat);
System.out.println (Integer.toHexString(qtySat & 0xff));
```

prints

```
-50
ce
```

Comment: my number supposed not to be negative so what is the best off the remove the ff ?

Comment: @user8012596 I wrote a suggestion how to remove it.

Comment: so I just add this & 0xff will it do meaning it will remove the leading ffffff?

Comment: how about my second scenario say it 2 byte then I want the extra leading 00 A1 . So when I run Integer.toHexString(serialNumber) I want the leading zeros to appear.

Comment: @user8012596 Yes, it will change to 0 the top 24 bits of the `int`, leaving the remaining bottom 8 bits unchanged.

Comment: @user8012596 You will have to add the leading 0s yourself. You can check the length of the hex String and add as many leading 0s as you want.

Comment: I dont get you what you mean by  it will change to 0 the top 24 bits of the int, leaving the remaining bottom 8 bits unchanged.

Comment: @user8012596 It will change `11111111111111111111111111001110` (ffffffce) to `00000000000000000000000011001110` (ce).

Comment: sorry got mixed up so mean this step qtySat & 0xff will create this 00000000000000000000000011001110 ok I got it now.

Comment: how to solve my this issue Integer.toHexString(serialNumber) I get output as say A1 but I want the leading 00 A1 cause this 2 byte of data. What changes to Integer.toHexString should I do??

Comment: I am trying this System.out.println("TEST :"+String.format("%04X", serialNumber)); I am not too sure is this correct method ?

Answer (score 1):

if the byte (8 bits) ***qtySat*** variable is negative, then leading ones will be added when is promoted to an integer, wich is  what `Integer.toHexString(int)`  requires as parameter

to get rid off those you will need to ensure a non negative argument

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Math.abs(serialNumber)));
```

Comment: my number supposed not to be negative so what is the best off the remove the ff ?

Comment: @eran how about my second scenario say it 2 byte then I want the extra leading 00 A1 . So when I run Integer.toHexString(serialNumber)  I want the leading zeros to appear.

Comment: then mask it bitwise, see erans answer