# How to convert int to hex in java?

Tags: java, byte

```
public void int2byte(){
    int x = 128;
    byte y = (byte) x;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(y));
}
```

I got result ffffff80, why not 80?
I got result 7f when x = 127.

Comment: Because `toHexString()` requires an `int` parameter, so the *signed* `byte` is widened to `int` using sign-extension.

Comment: 127(int) = -128(byte) = -128(int) = 0xffffff80(int)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409773/why-have-leading-ffffff-for-single-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bytes are signed in Java.  When you cast `128` to a `byte`, it becomes `-128`.

The `int` `128`: 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000

The `byte` `-128`: 10000000

Then, when you widen it back to an `int` with `Integer.toHexString`, because it's now negative, it gets sign-extended.  This means that a bunch of `1` bits show up, explaining your extra `f` characters in the hex output.

You can convert it in an unsigned fashion using [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-) to prevent the sign extension.

> Converts the argument to an `int` by an unsigned conversion. In an unsigned conversion to an `int`, the high-order 24 bits of the `int` are zero and the low-order 8 bits are equal to the bits of the `byte` argument.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(y)));
```

An alternative is to bit-mask out the sign-extended bits by manually keeping only the 8 bits of the `byte`:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(y & 0xFF));
```

Either way, the output is:

```
80
```

Comment: Or by playing with shift operators: Shift the 8 bits to the outer left and then shift them unsigned back to the outer right `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(y << 24 >>> 24)); // 80`

Answer (score 2):

This is because a positive value of 128 cannot be represented with a signed byte

The range is `-128 to 127`

So your int becomes sign-extended so instead of 0x00000080 you get 0xffffff80

**Edit:** As others have explained:

Integer 128 shares the last 8 bits with the byte (-128)

The difference is that Integer 128 has leading zeros.

```
0x00000080    (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000)
```

while the byte -128 is just

```
      0x80    (1000 0000)
```

When you convert byte -128 using `Integer.toHexString()` it takes the leading 1 and sign-extends it so you get

```
0xffffff80    (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000)
```

Comment: Correct, but incomplete. You should show what the actual `byte` value is, i.e. `-128`, and explain why and where the sign-extension occurs.